# Mongoose and Angular Populate Issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I am new to mongoose and Angular and I am having an issue with mongoose's populate method.  I have the following two mongoose schemas

```
var JobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    jobName: String,
    jobType: String,
    status: String,
    examples: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Example'}]
});

mongoose.model('Job', JobSchema);
```

and

```
var ExampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: String,
    job: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Job'}
});

mongoose.model('Example', ExampleSchema);
```

So basically the `Job` schema contains `Example`'s.  I also have the following Express route for getting the `examples` from a particular `Job`.  I used [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#opening-rest-routes) to figure out how to do this.

```
var Job = mongoose.model('Job');
var Example = mongoose.model('Example');

router.get('/jobs/:job', function (req, res) {

        req.job.populate('examples', function (err, job) {

            if (err) {return next(err);}

            res.json(job);
        });

    });
```

Also, I am using the following to automatically retrieve the `job` from mongo and attach it to `req`.

```
router.param('job', function (req, res, next, id) {
    var query = Job.findById(id);

    query.exec(function (err, job) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!job) {
            return next(new Error('can\'t find job'));
        }

        req.job = job;

        return next();
    });
});
```

I also have the following Angular factory that uses this route

```
app.factory('jobs', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var o = {    
        jobs: []
    };

    o.get = function (id) {
        return $http.get('/jobs/' + id).then(function (res) {
            return res.data;
        });
    };

    return o;
}]);
```

I also created the following state which is supposed to immediately populate the `examples` for a given `Job` id using the above factory.

```
.state('jobs', {
                url: '/jobs/{id}',
                templateUrl: '/jobs.html',
                controller: 'NerCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    post: ['$stateParams', 'jobs', function ($stateParams, jobs) {
                        return jobs.get($stateParams.id);
                    }]
                }
            });
```

The problem comes when I actually try to show the `examples` using a controller.

```
app.controller('NerCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'job',
    function ($scope, job) {

        $scope.examples = job.examples;

    }]);
```

The view that tries to use `$scope.examples` just displays `{{examples}}` rather than the actual content of the scope variable.  In fact, nothing in the controller seems to work with the `` `job` `` injection (not even simple 'alerts').

It looks the problem comes from the `` `job` `` injection in the controller.  This is supposed to refer to the `job` that is retrieved in the `resolve` given the id but it doesn't look like this is working.

In addition, I have curled an example record's url (eg. `curl http://localhost:3000/jobs/56920a1329cda48f16fc0815`) and it does return the desired `Job` record, so it does look like the route part is working correctly.  I suspect the problem is somewhere in the '`resolve'` or the way in which I am injecting the result of the `resolve` into the controller.

Comment: your server-side code looks strage. What should `req.job` contain? Are you using `express` for your routing? your models should be saved in variables like: `var Job = mongoose.model('Job', JobSchema);`. Also you should populate over the mongoose models like this: `Jobs.find(/* SOME QUERY */).populate('examples').exec(function() { ...})`. BTW: Your `Job` model contains `Example`s and `Example`s contains `Job`s. That is redundant.... why don't you just save the exmaples contents as `[String]` in `Job`?

Comment: Hi @marcel I am using ```express``` for routing and i do have the ```var Job = ...``` (I edited my question to show this).  I am following the populate syntax from [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#opening-rest-routes).  And when I curl, I do get the desired ```Job``` record in json.  Also, I plan on adding more fields to the ```Example``` schema in the future.

Comment: I also forgot to add the important ```router. param(...``` code.  I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was a silly mistake.  The `post` inside the `Job` state should have been `job`.  i.e.

```
.state('jobs', {
                url: '/jobs/{id}',
                templateUrl: '/jobs.html',
                controller: 'NerCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    job: ['$stateParams', 'jobs', function ($stateParams, jobs) {
                        return jobs.get($stateParams.id);
                    }]
                }
            });
```

In my inexperience, I did not know what `post` was referring to, but I suppose it refers to the job that is returned from `jobs.get($stateParams.id)` which is then the name that gets injected in the controller.  So obviously the name in `resolve` must be consistent with what is injected in the controller.